# Classification of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras of dimension 1, 2 and 3

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the class I am attending, after the first definitions, the professor classified the $\mathbb{C}$ algebras of dimension 1, 2 and 3. Right after, he invited us to go and think about the classification of $\mathbb R$ algebras of dimension 1, 2 and 3.

Here I am not sure how to proceed. Any hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For any $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $(\mathbb{V}, \ast)$, $\ast$ extends by complex (bi)linearity to a complex bilinear map $\ast_{\mathbb{C}}$ on the complex vector space $\mathbb{V}_{\mathbb{C}} := \mathbb{V} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ whose complex dimension coincides with the real dimension of $\mathbb{V}$. Hence, $(\mathbb{V}_{\mathbb{C}}, \ast_{\mathbb{C}})$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra, but you already have the classification of these in the dimensions of interest.

Comment: I can't really understand exactly what you mean.. The professor observed that in this case the field is not closed, probably I have to use this somehow.

Comment: It means that if you have any $k$-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-algebra, you can produce a $k$-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-algebra by "complexifying" it, but for $k = 1, 2, 3$, any $\mathbb{C}$- algebra produced this way must be on your list of such algebras. So, one tack is, for each $\mathbb{C}$-algebra on your list, find all of the $\mathbb{R}$-algebras that produce it via complexification. If you need a different sort of hint, it would be useful if you included a little more about the proof of the $\mathbb{C}$ case and some context, e.g., some information about the course itself.